# How can I import pygame without "from pygame.locals import *"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, python-import

I tried to use `pygame` without doing the `from pygame.locals import *` that is suggested in nearly all tutorials. I thought that I should be able to access anything within `pygame.locals` by explictly stating the path I get it from. However, this leads to an `AttributeError` for me.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
print pygame.locals.QUIT
```

For me, this yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'locals'
```

I use Python 2.7.5+ and pygame 1.9.1release.

Why can't I use `pygame.locals.QUIT`? When I insert `from pygame.locals import *` I can use `QUIT` just as it is supposed to.

I found this link: http://nullege.com/codes/search/pygame.locals.QUIT where the usage I tried is exemplified.

Comment: Any reason why `pygame.QUIT` doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the variables are in `pygame` when I do not `import pygame.locals`. I can't find that documented in the pygame documentation. I guess I didn't quite get http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html . So - if I do not use `import pygame.locals` everything is just in `import pygame` as in your `pygame.QUIT`?

Comment: @user2076855 the contents of `pygame.locals` are made available in the root `pygame` namespace (e.g. `pygame.QUIT`) by `import pygame`. They can be imported into the global namespace (e.g. just `QUIT`) by `from pygame.locals import *`. But they can't be accessed via `pygame.locals`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `import pygame.locals` as well, not just `import pygame`.